# shapely object.buffer(0) return a empty polygon(coordinates:[]),and discard the main polygon

Tags: python, buffer, shapely, self-intersection

There are self-intersect polygons in my geojson files.So I used the shapely lib to fix it.
The code is like this:

```
clean = geom.buffer(0)
```

Most of the polygons have been processed properly,but there are still few polygons returned empty,which coordinates are empty array.

The result geometry "clean" delete the polygon but preserve the line.

The polygon is as follows:
[the self-intersect polygon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NCdi.png)

the  feature in geojson format:

```
      {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "wrong",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "value": 98 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 117.071654, 40.213989 ], [ 117.071654, 40.213965 ], [ 117.071643, 40.213956 ], [ 117.071643, 40.21394 ], [ 117.071632, 40.213932 ], [ 117.071632, 40.213915 ], [ 117.071621, 40.213907 ], [ 117.071621, 40.213883 ], [ 117.071611, 40.213875 ], [ 117.071611, 40.213858 ], [ 117.0716, 40.21385 ], [ 117.0716, 40.213834 ], [ 117.071589, 40.213825 ], [ 117.071589, 40.213801 ], [ 117.071579, 40.213793 ], [ 117.071579, 40.213784 ], [ 117.071568, 40.213776 ], [ 117.071546, 40.213776 ], [ 117.071536, 40.213784 ], [ 117.071514, 40.213784 ], [ 117.071514, 40.213686 ], [ 117.071525, 40.213678 ], [ 117.071525, 40.213563 ], [ 117.0716, 40.213563 ], [ 117.071611, 40.213555 ], [ 117.071697, 40.213555 ], [ 117.071707, 40.213547 ], [ 117.071697, 40.213539 ], [ 117.071697, 40.21353 ], [ 117.071675, 40.213514 ], [ 117.071782, 40.213514 ], [ 117.071804, 40.21353 ], [ 117.071815, 40.21353 ], [ 117.071847, 40.213555 ], [ 117.072244, 40.213555 ], [ 117.072244, 40.213752 ], [ 117.072093, 40.213752 ], [ 117.072083, 40.213743 ], [ 117.071911, 40.213743 ], [ 117.071879, 40.213768 ], [ 117.071868, 40.213768 ], [ 117.071847, 40.213784 ], [ 117.071664, 40.213784 ], [ 117.071654, 40.213793 ], [ 117.071654, 40.213989 ] ] ] } }
]
}
```

How can I erase the "line" and only preserve the orange polygon？

Comment: You can try to use very small value instead of 0.

Comment: @martinfleis，I have used 1e-6，but got the same result.